# Problem with code that increments a identity column in an insert statement in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I read a post for inserting rows into a table that has an identity column but it does not work. Here is the code what am I missing? When, I run it I get this error message:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PP_ID', table 
Med.dbo.tblPledgePayments column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

If, I add the identity column to the insert statement (PP_ID) then instead of adding the next logical number sixteen (16) the table has fifteen (15) rows it adds rows starting from one (1). How can I overcome this?

```
DECLARE @TxtHowMuch as int,
    @TxtHowMany as int,
    @TxtPledgeStartDt as datetime,
    @TxtFrequency as nvarchar(50), -- Yearly, Monthly, Qurterly
    @PaymentNumber as int,
    @GID as int,
    @cnt INT = 0                   --Constant


--These values will be brought in from Access
SET @TxtHowMuch = 100000
SET @TxtHowMany = 10
SET @TxtPledgeStartDt = '2018-01-01'
SET @TxtFrequency = 'Yearly'
SET @PaymentNumber = 1
SET @GID = 200

While @cnt < @TxtHowMany
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblPledgePayments] 
(PP_schedule, GiftID, PP_DueDate, PP_Amount)

Select 
 @PaymentNumber, @GID,

Case
    WHEN @TxtFrequency = 'Yearly'    THEN DateAdd(YEAR,    @cnt, @TxtPledgeStartDt)
    WHEN @TxtFrequency = 'Monthly'   THEN DateAdd(MONTH,   @cnt, @TxtPledgeStartDt)
    WHEN @TxtFrequency = 'Quarterly' THEN DateAdd(QUARTER, @cnt, @TxtPledgeStartDt)
END 

,@TxtHowMuch / @TxtHowMany   

SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
SET @PaymentNumber = @PaymentNumber + 1;

END;
```

Comment: Can you show us how your table is set up? At the moment it sounds like  it isn't set up to do autonumbering...

Comment: In addition to the table not having an identity you do NOT want to use a loop for inserts like this. Can you share details of your table? [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: You are correct the table was not setup for auto numbering. I have made the correction and it works fine now.